# How to prepare data for CLVTools::clvdata()

Tags: r, data-mining

I'm trying to do an CLV analysis in R using the CLVTools package. This package is, according to the authors, an improved version for the BTYD package.
I have no experience in this package so I'm sure this problem can be fixed fairly easily.

My data consists of a client_id, transaction_date and total_revenue, where each obsevation represents a customer purchase. This is all the data required in order to conduct a CLV analysis in my context.

The problem occours when I try to create the CLV data object using the `clvdata()` function.
I get the error message:

```
Error: Parameter estimation.split needs to indicate a point at least 2 periods before the last transaction!
```

I wasn't able to find any explanation of why this occours, my data looks the same as the data they use for their example.

Here is the `clvdata()` function with parameters included:

```
clv.apparel <- clvdata(Data_for_CLV,  
                   date.format="ymd", 
                   time.unit = "week",
                   estimation.split = 40,
                   name.id = "Client_ID",
                   name.date = "Transaction_Date",
                   name.price = "Total_Revenue")
```

--------EDIT--------

After removing the `estimate.split` I was able to train the pareto/nbd model on the whole dataset, and got the results underneath. However, I would also like to use the model for prediction, which requires a holdout period. If I understand you correctly, SmokeyShakers, I should now be able to set the `estimation.split` to something valid, which is what exactly?

````
> summary(est.pnbd)
Pareto NBD Standard  Model 

Call:
pnbd(clv.data = clv.apparel)

Fitting period:                               
Estimation start   2019-12-21   
Estimation end     2020-08-21   
Estimation length  34.8571 Weeks

Coefficients:
      Estimate Std. Error  z-val Pr(>|z|)    
r      0.29540    0.02195 13.459  < 2e-16 ***
alpha 21.59114    1.18486 18.223  < 2e-16 ***
s      0.76215    0.04841 15.745  < 2e-16 ***
beta   1.45651    0.27221  5.351 8.76e-08 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Optimization info:                  
LL     -26233.7198
AIC    52475.4396 
BIC    52512.0753 
KKT 1  TRUE       
KKT 2  TRUE       
fevals 26.0000    
Method L-BFGS-B   

Used Options:                 
Correlation FALSE```
````

Comment: Basically, you're trying to holdout data you don't seem to have. Set it `estimation.split = NULL` and try running without a holdout

Comment: Isn't the `estimation.split` suppose to split the data so you can evaluate the model? Is it still possible to evaluate the model if I skip the `estimation.split`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. My suggestion was so you could see exactly where you could split your data.  Then you'd set `estimation.split` to something valid.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Where can I find the suggestion for a valid split? I have updated the post with information from the summary of the model.
If I set the split lower than 30 weeks, I get a new message:
`Error: The estimation split is too short! Not all customers of this cohort had their first actual transaction until the specified estimation.split!`

Comment: I've only used BTYD, but you can already see you only have 34 weeks of data. You can't have customers with their first transaction after the split.

Comment: What is the easiest way of fixing the data in the holdout period to not include new customers?

Comment: Ultimately you need every Client_Id to have a minimum Transaction_Date before your holdout. This is a data manipulation question with a lot of good answers on this site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Disclaimer: Im a co-creator of the package*

These probabilistic models of latent attrition are usually applied on customer **cohorts** because it is assumed that cohorts substantially differ from each other. Hence, you fit one separate model on each cohort. Most commonly the definition of cohorts refers to the join-date (=first transaction) but any other (further) definition is possible, such as by channel or by business segment.
See also Fader and Hardie (2010) about why to cohort-wise application is important:  http://www.brucehardie.com/papers/022/fader_hardie_mksc_10.pdf

But regardless of your exact cohort definition, all customers are required to have made their first transaction during the estimation period:
The model is fit on the transaction data that is present in the estimation period. For all customers that have made a transaction in the estimation period, the future number of transactions are predicted for the prediction horizon which you specify as if you were standing at the end of the estimation period. All customers therefore need to have made their first transaction in the estimation period in order for the model to "know" that they exist. The model can simply not make a prediction for a customer it does not know it exists (=did not make a transaction in the estimation period).

The package could simply remove the customers that do not make their first transaction in the estimation period and only make predictions for the ones that do. However, we believe that user should be aware what happens and therefore consciously prepare the data him/herself.

> I should now be able to set the estimation.split to something valid,
> which is what exactly

You have to specify the estimation end to a date by which all the customers in your data have already made their first transaction. If this is not the case in your data, you should split your data into cohorts defined by first transaction.

Say you have customers transactions from 2015-01-01 until 2020-01-01 and would like to split at 2017-01-01. Then you could define the first cohort as all customers that made their first transaction (=joined) between 2015-01-01 to 2015-12-31 and the second cohort from 2016-01-01 to 2016-12-31. You would create 2 separate clvdata objects for each cohort and then also fit 2 separate models. Note that you cannot create a third cohort from 2017-01-01 to 2018-01-01 with the estimation split at 2017-01-01, rather for this 3rd cohort you would have to define a later split date, say 2019-01-01.

Other cohorting windows such as 1month, 3month, 6month etc are also customary but depend on your data. Make sure to choose an estimation period long enough for the model to actually see the repeat-purchase patterns per customer (check mean interpurchase time in `summary(clvdata)`). For this reason, the estimation period is commonly longer than the cohorting window, ie the estimation end for a cohort is  after max(customer_join_date). You might also be interested in my more in-depth answer about data preparation and cohort-wise analysis here:

https://github.com/bachmannpatrick/CLVTools/issues/101

https://github.com/bachmannpatrick/CLVTools/issues/146

> However, I would also like to use the model for prediction, which
> requires a holdout period

After you have successfully fit the model, you can **always make a prediction, also without holdout period**. However, you have to specify the `prediction.end` argument to tell how far ahead you want to predict (number of periods or exact date). You do not have to specify the `prediction.end` if your data has a holdout period, because it then defaults to the holdout period. The same applies for `prediction.end` in `plot()`.
To make your final CLV prediction, its actually customary to fit the model on all data in the cohort (ie without holdout period)

Answer (score 1):

I am currently working with the same package and had a similar issue. The problem was that **some customers had their first transaction during the holdout period** (and no transaction during the calibration period). Other packages (such as BTYD and BTYDplus) seem to automatically filter those cases, but CLVTools does not.

Therefore, **you have to filter those cases by hand** (i.e. customers whose first transaction happend during the holdout period).

Comment: Thanks! In your case, what method did you use to filter out the new customers in the holdout period? Did you use BTYD package for that? or did you do it manually? If you can show an example with some code, that would be much appriciated.